# How to convert string and integer to binary in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, binary

I have the following problems. I have an integer and a string. Both of them need to be converted into binary format. For the integer I found a solution that, as far as I can tell, works. The string on the other hand, I don't have a solid understanding of it.

String(16), as far as I understand, means something like `Array<UInt8>` and has a fixed length of 16. Am I correct? If so, is there a better way to converting them by hand built in in NodeJS?

```js
const myNumber = 2
const myString = 'MyString'

const myNumberInBinary = toUInt16(myNumber) // eg. 0000000000000101
const myStringinBinary = toString16(myString) // I honestly don't know

function toUInt16(number) {
    let binaryString = Number(number).toString(2)
    while (binaryString.length < 16) {
        binaryString = '0' + binaryString
    }
    return binaryString
}

// TODO: implement
function toString16(string) {
    ...
    return binaryString
}
```

best regards

EDIT:
Thanks for all the comments and the answer.  They helped me understand this process better. The solution I ended up with is this one:

```
const bitString = "00000101"
const buffer = new Buffer.alloc(bitString.length / 8)

for (let i = 0; i < bitString.length; i++) {
  const value = bitString.substring(i * 8, (i * 8) + 8)
  buffer[i] = Number(value)        
}

fs.writeFileSync('my_file', buffer, 'binary')
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you need the conversion?

Comment: Are you sure that the string "0000000000000101", which would be like '\x30\x30...\x30\x31\x30\x31', which consists of [0b110000, 0b110000, ...., 0b110000, 0b110001, 0b110000, 0b110001], is the actual thing required? NodeJS can write actual binary files. ASCII '0' characters are not just 0 bits, and '1' characters are not just 1 bits either

Comment: @qrsngky you could be right. I how would I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about your requirements, but there are functions designed for that: `buf.readUIntLE` and `but.writeUIntLE` for non-negative integers and `Buffer.from(...)` and `buf.toString(...)` for strings.
Are the integers in your program only from 0 to 65535?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through the string and do this on each character:

```html
 let result = ""
 
 for (let i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
      result += myString[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
  }
```